# RStudio, R, Sports Analytics - Adding Multiple Teams for one row (player)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-science

I am trying to add the team for each player into a data frame in R. The data is below.

```
 name          team  goals
 <chr>         <chr> <dbl>
1 John Smith    DAL       3
2 John Smith    DAL       5
3 John Smith    TOR       5
4 Patrick Lewis MTL       1
5 Patrick Lewis MTL       2
```

After transformation:

```
  name            team         goals
  <chr>           <chr>        <dbl>
1 John Smith     DAL, TOR       13
2 Patrick Lewis   MTL           3
```

My initial thought was to use dplyr to mutate the team column to get the desired result.

Assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Brad, I think your question is a little vague at the moment. What format is the data available as? It generally helps to provide a sample of each data; the gold-standard is to paste the output from `dput(x)` where `x` is a representative *sample* of your real data. Since you have two frames, please make sure there are matches in the two in order to best demonstrate the steps.

Comment: Hello @r2evans, Thank you for the comment. I have modified the initial post to provide a better example of the transformation.